# Class in menu link

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have this code to do a menu in my app, and i need to add a class type to this one.

```
<?php
                                echo $this->Html->link('Home Page',
                                    array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'home_page'),
                                    array('escape'=> false)).' | ';
                            ?>
```

Can you help me please?
How can add it?

Comment: This is very clearly explained in the book.  Please try that resource before asking here.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->Html->link('Home Page', array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'home_page'),array('escape'=>false ,'class'=>'yourclass'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see [HtmlHelper::link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3alink):

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link('Home Page',
    array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'home_page'),
    array('class' => 'button', 'escape'=> false)
) . ' | ';
```